# allocating node on the heap, difference between first assign to NULL and direct assignment with malloc [c]

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack, malloc

I am trying to implement a stack using linked list, and firstly I have the following code:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;               // integer data
    struct Node* next;      // pointer to the next node
} Node;


Node* inti_stack() {
    Node* node = NULL;// allocate a new node in a heap
    node = malloc(sizeof * node);
    if (!node) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return node;
}
```

For the `inti_stack` function, can I just do the following and that would be equivalent?

```
Node* inti_stack() {
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof * node);
    if (!node) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return node;
}
```

Comment: `Node* node = malloc(sizeof * node);` is initialisation, not assignment. `Node* node = NULL;` is also initialisation; the difference is that it initialises to a constant (`NULL`). Initialisation with constants is only required for variables declared at the top-level; since `node` is declared inside a function, there is no restriction on the value it is being initialised to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code snippet

```
Node* node = NULL;// allocate a new node in a heap
node = malloc(sizeof * node);
```

the declared pointer `node` is at once overwritten.

So it is enough to write

```
Node* node = malloc(sizeof * node);
```

If the function `malloc` is unable to allocate memory it returns a null pointer.

Pay attention to that the name of the function `inti_stack` is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case:

```
Node* node = NULL;// allocate a new node in a heap
node = malloc(sizeof * node);
```

The value of `node` is determinate. `malloc()` will overwrite it with a pointer to a chunk of heap memory if it succeeded.

In the second case:

```
Node* node = malloc(sizeof * node);
```

The value of `node` is indeterminate, but it's going to be overwritten by `malloc()` nevertheless.

So yes, they're both equivalent. Though the latter is preferred.

NB that `malloc()` will return a `NULL` pointer on failure, and set `errno` on some implementations. Your code should check for it.

Aside: Why `exit()` without an error message?

```
if (!node) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
/* I'd expect a fprintf()/perror() here */
```